# How do I enter escape characters in eclipse expressions (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm attempting to use escape characters in the Expressions window in Eclipse for Java. If I enter:

```
filename.startsWith("C:")
```

that evaluates to `true`. But if I change it to either of these:

```
filename.startsWith("C:\\")
filename.startsWith("C:\")
```

I get "<errors during the evaluation>".

I'm actually trying to enter a conditional breakpoint to match a filepath; it doesn't show `\<errors during the evaluation\>`, but it also doesn't stop, so my theory is that there's something I'm doing incorrectly with the escaped backslash character in both places. What is it?

Comment: In Java in a String one backslash must be written as two backslashes. What's the `filename`? Depending on how you get it, the backslashes might be already converted to regular slashes (`/`).

Comment: Call it "c:\local\temp\". I can enter it as `c:\\local\\temp\\ ` or `c:\local\temp\ `, I get the error either way.

Comment: Mhh, now `C` turns into `c`, but `startsWith(...)` is case sensitive. Just tell the exact value of `filename` that you found out by debugging or by adding the line `System.out.println(filename);`, not by guessing.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. It does not matter what `filename` is, as long as it's a non-null string. The expression window is refusing to recognize the literal passed as a parameter to `startsWith()`, whether I enter escape characters for the backslashes or not. I'm asking how that literal is supposed to be entered. I know `startsWith()` is case sensitive. The error appears when the program is stopped at a breakpoint and I'm entering expressions for the debugger to display. I'm not guessing anything; once I can get the expressions straight, I'll handle debugging the program.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter it as `filename.startsWith("C:\\\\")` which looks to me like a bug, so make sure it has been reported to Eclipse JDT.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the Eclipse expression evaluator seems to have problems with expressions that contain strings containing escape characters.  You have to add extra escape characters to the strings to get it to work.  This one gave me problems: filename.split("//.").  That's valid Java but to get it to work in the Eclipse expression evaluator you need to enter filename.split("////.")

Comment: I've been getting feedback that indicates that's how the expression evaluator works.  When you enter a string that itself uses escape characters, the evaluator needs an extra "\" entered.  If you look at the expression after you key it in, those extra "\" characters don't get displayed unless you put your cursor over them.  It just how the evaluator input method seems to work.  Definitely very confusing.  If you copy and paste some valid Java code that has a string containing some escape characters, you may get an error and will have to manually add those extra escape characters. Not intuitive

Comment: I took the time to file this as a bug with the Eclipse team.  Hopefully I get a definitive answer if that how it's designed to work or whether it is a bug.

Comment: @TomRutchik Eclipse is open source, so you do best not only file a bug report but also propose a solution. Changing the behavior would break use cases so it might better to document it explaining the reason for it and to visualize escape characters. Please link to the issue.